# I Can't get my exact location using expo-location

Tags: javascript, react-native

THE CODE USING REACT-NATIVE AND EXPO-LOCATION:

```
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Alert,
    SafeAreaView,
    RefreshControl,
    StyleSheet,
    ActivityIndicator,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import React, {
    useEffect,
    useState
} from 'react';
import * as Location from 'expo-location'

const openWeatherKey = 'cbb62d0f2653b471dbf6ca28aebb813f'
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?&units=metric&exclude=minutely&appid=${openWeatherKey}`

const Weather = () => {
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null)
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)

const loadForecast = async () => {
    setRefreshing(true)
    const {
        status
    } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        Alert.alert('Permission to acces location was denied')
    }
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    })

    const response = await fetch(`${url}&lat=${location.coords.latitude}&lon=${location.coords.longitude}`)
    const data = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('error something went wrong')
    } else {
        setForecast(data);
    }
    setRefreshing(false)
}

useEffect(() => {
    loadForecast()
}, [])

if (!forecast) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.loading}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size='large'/>
              </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const current = forecast.current.weather[0]

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView
                  refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl 
                    refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={() => loadForecast()}/>
                  }
                  style={{marginTop:50}}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.title}>
                    Current Weather 
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{alignItems:'center', textAlign:'center'}}>
                    Your Location
                  </Text>
                  <View>
    
                  </View>
                  </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
)
}
export default Weather

)
```

THE ERROR: 'Error something went wrong'
But i dont understand why he is not able to get the location?

Does somebody know the answer? i think it goes wrong at const response. Also when i use the standard Code for gettting a location from expo-location docs it works?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: I have formatted the code my bad Ahmet